# I need to confirm changes made with the "return-key" since I updated to 3.6

Tags: modeling, interface, workflow

Just as the title says, since I updated to blender version 3.6, I need to confirm actions and changes like inserting loop cuts, (un-)parenting, adding crease and bevel values, etc. It is really annoying, since it is absolutly disturbing my workflow. Previously releasing the mouse button or clicking on the command always confirmed the action. Im unable to figure out where I could disable this "feature".

I would appreciate any help and hints,

Have a great day

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Exactly what do you mean by "need to confirm actions and changes"?

Comment: well, e.g. i add an edge loop to the mesh. Previously as soon as I clicked the left or right mouse button, the edgeloop was added and i could continue working. But now i first have to "confirm" it by pressing return. Otherwise im unable to select any edges vertices or faces.

Comment: Do you use a mac? If yes idk if things were previously different on mac. Coz atleast on windows, we have to click ctrl+r to loop cut and then slide it if we want to and confirm by pressing enter or just clicking. I started using blender since 2.79. It's always been like that. Of course while using the toolbar loop cut we just have to select the tool, select the location of the yellow line and click to perform the loop cut.

Comment: @NiklasFriedrichs idk what kind of m!n!ac did the downvoting for the question , but this alone caused me to not to upgrade

Comment: @Akshay2005 yeah i know, but since i upgraded to 3.6 i have to press enter, if not i'm unable to selct any verts, edges or faces. Just clicking isn't working anymore.